# Minimize a multivariable cost function from measurement data?

Tags: optimization, matlab, least-squares

This is a simple problem. Normaly I use two for-loops in GNU Octave to find the parameter $a$ and $b$ and $K$.

The cost function I'm going to minimize is:

$$V = \sum_{i = 0}^N(|u_i - K - u_0a^{-bt_i}|)$$

Where $u_i$ is a vector for measurement and $t_i$ is also a measured vector. $u_0$ is known so only $a, b, K$ is unknow.

Is there any other way to minimize $V$ instead of using three for-loops in GNU Octave?

In my case, two-variables can solve the problem too. The K is just a correction factor. Not necessary to 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at `fminsearch`? It can minimize a cost function over several parameters (just put them together in one vector). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764973/minimizing-a-multivariable-function) are [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661375/how-do-i-use-fminsearch-to-solve-this-4-variable-objective-function-matlab?rq=1).

Comment: Can fminsearch handle discrete mesurement data?

Comment: Yes, see the examples.